# Double screen in one, issue with vega 8

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, hp, radeon, amd-graphics

Recently I bought a HP pavilion 15 cw-0009la
with AMD ryzen 5 y amd radeon vega 8.
The problem is when I use any Ubuntu version on this laptop the screen shows double, in settings it show two screens but there is only one.

Someone have any idea how to solve it?

[image: there is all the time]

---

<sub>recientemente cambie mi laptop por una hp pavilion 15 cw-0009la con un amd ryzen 5 y amd radeon vega 8. El problema es que al iniciar ubuntu live se parte la pantalla en dos y en ambas muestra lo mismo pero en una misma pantalla, si entro a la configuracion marca que detecta dos pantallas, a demas de que de la mitad para abajo solo se estira la ultima linea visible como se muestra en la imagen de abajo Alguna idea de como solucionarlo ?? ya probre ubuntu live 15, 16, 18</sub>

Comment: Someone else seems to have the same graphical issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065405/duplicate-screen-when-starting-ubuntu-18-04 .It's not something I've seen before but I very much suspect it's AMD Graphics driver related. The other question says that it was working fine for a while but seems to have gone 'double screen' after a recent update. Is it the same for you or does any Ubuntu live USB (16.04, 18.04, 17.10 etc) have the same issue?

Comment: I've the same issue with all ubuntu live versions I tryed (15-18)

Comment: Hi again - I was hoping someone with experience and knowledge of AMD would have offered some advice by now. If you haven't found a fix yet, my best guess is that the Vega graphics support isn't quite up to scratch yet in the 4.15 kernel and that it might be worth trying installing 18.04 and then using the Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility to try it with a 4.18 kernel. UKUU details here: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu

Comment: Just install ubuntu 18.10, yet in release candidate but should work out of the box