# Duplicate screen when starting Ubuntu 18.04 on laptop with AMD Graphics

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, 17.04, startup, amd-graphics

When I start my HP laptop, I see double GRUB window. Sometimes I must start up and shut down the laptop for 10-20 times until it runs correctly.

There is also a problem with shutting down the laptop. When I work on the laptop more than a few minutes, sometimes shut down takes over 5-10 mins. I didn't have this problem since upgraded from Ubuntu 17, only from few weeks (maybe it's because of some Ubuntu update?). It’s really annoying, maybe somebody has the solution?

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Hi reggae-krk - haven't seen anything like those screenshots before but it looks like some sort of graphical issue. Do you have nVidia graphics on your HP Laptop?

Comment: I get this output from lspci | grp VGA conson command:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)

Comment: Looks like you've got AMD Radeon graphics. Have a search for AMD Radeon issues and see if anyone else has been having similar problems.

Comment: I try to update drivers from sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers but its even worst

Comment: Someone else with similar issue with AMD Graphics: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063064/double-screen-in-one-issue-with-vega-8

Comment: I'd recommend editing your question to mention that you have AMD Graphics on this laptop. I've not got any experience of using them, but someone else might. An option is to try reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04 and see if the problem persists. Unless someone with a bit more experience of AMD issues has any suggestions, then it's probably the easiest thing to try.

Comment: Did reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04 fix the issue? Does trying a newer 4.17 or 4.18 kernel help? You can try a newer kernel using the Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu

Comment: I will reinstall Ubuntu in this week or just install Manjaro but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue.
Try To select boot mode to UEFI in Bios and install ubuntu